# How do i check if client still alive

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, client-server

I have seen that question have asked before, But he have not got an answer.
I have a client server program that I wrote by myself. I use sockets on tcp protocol to connect between the server and the client.

My question is how can I check that the client is stiil alive? I had an idea. every 1 second for example the server will send a buffer to the client. The client will send back the buffer and the server will know he is alive. This idea is good? or there is another way to do it?

Comment: You could always check his pulse. Try to send a small packet; if it throws an exception you can declare him dead.

Comment: Have a read about SignalR. Maybe you can see what they use to achieve this.